# What is the mathematical relationship between R2 and MSE?

Tags: regression, r-squared

Trying to understand this relationship I came across this conversation in an email group:

> > I got a problem while analyzing my data using NN.
> >      I got R-square with 0.45 with MSE around 5000.
> >     SO I am wonder why? There must be a relation
> >     between R-square and MSE?
>
> R2 = 1 - SSE/SS0
>
> SSE = N*MSE SS0 = (N-1)*VAR(Target)
>
> VAR(T) = SS0/(N-1) = [SSE/(1-R2)]/(N-1)
>
> = [N/N-1]*MSE/(1-R2)
>
> ~ 5000/0.55 ~ 9091
>
> If you had standardized your targets to unit variance you would have
>   obtained MSE ~ 0.55

Is that correct?
What insights can we reach understanding this relationship?

Answer (score 34):

Yes, allow me to elaborate.

Recall that for some outcome $y_i \in \mathbb{R}, \forall i=1,2,..,n$ we define MSE and $\textrm{R}^2$ as

\begin{equation}
\textrm{MSE}(y, \hat{y} ) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \hat{y_i})^{2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\textrm{R}^2(y, \hat{y} ) = 1 - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \hat{y_i})^{2}}{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \bar{y})^{2} }
\end{equation}

So, as you noted, $\textrm{R}^2$ is a normalized version of MSE, we use MSE for reporting because I think it's a simple metric and it is technically the loss-function we are minimizing when we solve the normal equations.

$\textrm{R}^2$ is useful because it is often easier to interpret since it doesn't depend on the scale of the data.

As a concrete example, consider two models: one predicting income and the other predicting age, $\textrm{R}^2$ will make it easier to state which model is performing better.*

---

*In general, this isn't a great idea and you shouldn't compare metrics like $\textrm{R}^2$ across different models to make these sorts of claims because some things are just fundamentally harder to predict than others (e.g., stock markets vs. who survived the Titanic).