# How to choose between R2 and MSE scores?

Tags: regression, mse

I have a dataset with approximately 2500 observations and 50 variables. The response variable is numerical, so my objective is to build a regression model. I have built one penalized linear regression model and one xgboost regressor model.

The linear model has obtained a MSE of 7.31 and a R2 score of 0.62
The xgboost model has obtained a MSE of 8.19 and a R2 of 0.66

So one model has the smallest MSE but the other has the largest R2. Which one is better? I have read that there are some metrics that are called "proper", meaning that it is mathematically proven that the better the metric, the better the model. I was wondering if either the MSE or R2 are proper.

Comment: You have to pay attention to the [exact $R^2$ calculation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590199/how-to-motivate-the-definition-of-r2-in-sklearn-metrics-r2-score) in order to interpret its meaning and if it should be meaningful to you. Do you know what calculation is performed, even if it is just a software function?

Comment: Well, I am using scikit-learn's function `r2_score`, which receives a vector of true response values and a vector of predictions and from what I have seen, it computes the value as 1 - (residual sum of squares / total sum of squares)

Comment: That’s the exact function that I speculate in the linked question has no statistical motivation and is not meaningful beyond being an approximation to the formula I give at the end of that question. My stance now has support in the statistics literature, with the citation included in that linked question.

Comment: What do you input into the `r2_score` function for each model?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your calculation - or the two models were evaluated on different samples.

See the formula for MSE and $R^2$: [What is the mathematical relationship between R2 and MSE?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/250730/what-is-the-mathematical-relationship-between-r2-and-mse)